# Linux CentOS rename files for every directory with known structure

Tags: linux, centos

I have lots of directories with the same structure. A specific folder in a directory can contain a file, that I want to rename.

`mv /home/*?*/domains/*?*/public/old.text /home/*?*/domains/*?*/public/new.txt`

The *?* can be different each time.

I tried the above, but didn't work of course.

It's on a Linux CentOS machine.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
for i in /home/*/domains/*/public/; do
    echo mv "$i/old.txt" "$i/new.txt"
done
```

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected symbol : '/home/*/domains/*/public_html/'

Comment: @user2382765 What shell are you using? csh?